# Move a robot with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

I am creating a robot that moves with Geometry Nodes.

It can move the body, an arm and a hand independently.
The problem is when it moves the hand and the arm at the same time. The hand comes out of the arm.

[image: If you move the arm and not the hand all goes well]
If you move the arm and not the hand all goes well

[image: If you move the arm and the hand it seems that the hand goes out of the arm]
If you move the arm and the hand it seems that the hand goes out of the arm.

[image: The geometry Nodes that moves the arm and the hand]
The geometry Nodes that moves the arm and the hand

Any idea to rotated the hand correctly?

Thanks for your help ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to solve the hand problem.

First, you need to turn your hand to the desired angle.
I use the 'transform' GN without translation.

Once the hand is correctl rotated I use a second 'transform' GN with translation and the rotation to follow the arm.

[image: Good GN]
With this GN, the hand stays attached to the arm in any situation

[Video of the hand](https://youtu.be/3NjTI6licWI)